Partition by column, order by another
I am simulating a SQL query with the following values:
rows = [(1, '2021/04', 'Shop 2', 341227.53), (2, '2021/05', 'Shop 2', 315447.24), (3, '2021/06', 'Shop 1', 1845662.35), (4, '2021/04', 'Shop 2', 21487.63), (5, '2021/05', 'Shop 1', 1489774.16), (6, '2021/06', 'Shop 1', 52489.35), (7, '2021/04', 'Shop 1', 154552.82), (8, '2021/05', 'Shop 2', 6548.49), (9, '2021/06', 'Shop 2', 387779.49)]

I want to build a dictionary of a 'window' function. It should partition on the third column (ex value: 'shop1') and order by the second column (ex value: '2021/06').
So, it should look like this:
{
    'Shop 1': ['2021/04', '2021/05', ...],
    'Shop 2': [...],
    ...
}

Is there a way to do that such that I could define a lambda function taking two arguments, for example:
window_func = lambda partition_func, order_func: ...

The above partition_func would be item[2] and the order_func would be item[3].

Why do you need the window function? Just call the partitioning and order functions from the function that creates the dictionary.

And why is this a lambda? Named functions should generally be defined with def, lambda is mainly used for anonymous functions that are passed as arguments or stored in data structures.

@Barmar that's fine, let's do it that way. What would the function look like then?

@Barmar I was trying to use a 'functional approach', but I suppose it doesn't have to be.

def create_dictionary(partition_func, order_func):... It loops through the original list calling partition_func on each element to get the dictionary key, and appends to the element with that key (collections.defaultdict will be useful for this). After that's done, call order_func on each list to sort it.

Is order_func for ordering, or for extracting the values that you want to be in the dictionary lists? Maybe you need a third function for extracting.

Try:
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

rows = [
    (1, "2021/04", "Shop 2", 341227.53),
    (2, "2021/05", "Shop 2", 315447.24),
    (3, "2021/06", "Shop 1", 1845662.35),
    (4, "2021/04", "Shop 2", 21487.63),
    (5, "2021/05", "Shop 1", 1489774.16),
    (6, "2021/06", "Shop 1", 52489.35),
    (7, "2021/04", "Shop 1", 154552.82),
    (8, "2021/05", "Shop 2", 6548.49),
    (9, "2021/06", "Shop 2", 387779.49),
]

window_func = lambda partition_func, order_func: lambda x: {
    k: [order_func(v) for v in g]
    for k, g in groupby(
        sorted(x, key=lambda v: (partition_func(v), order_func(v))), partition_func
    )
}

fn = window_func(itemgetter(2), itemgetter(1))
print(fn(rows))

Prints:
{
    "Shop 1": ["2021/04", "2021/05", "2021/06", "2021/06"],
    "Shop 2": ["2021/04", "2021/04", "2021/05", "2021/05", "2021/06"],
}


EDIT: To get list of rows in the output:
window_func = lambda partition_func, order_func: lambda x: {
    k: list(g)
    for k, g in groupby(
        sorted(x, key=lambda v: (partition_func(v), order_func(v))), partition_func
    )
}

fn = window_func(itemgetter(2), itemgetter(1))
print(fn(rows))

Prints:
{
    "Shop 1": [
        (7, "2021/04", "Shop 1", 154552.82),
        (5, "2021/05", "Shop 1", 1489774.16),
        (3, "2021/06", "Shop 1", 1845662.35),
        (6, "2021/06", "Shop 1", 52489.35),
    ],
    "Shop 2": [
        (1, "2021/04", "Shop 2", 341227.53),
        (4, "2021/04", "Shop 2", 21487.63),
        (2, "2021/05", "Shop 2", 315447.24),
        (8, "2021/05", "Shop 2", 6548.49),
        (9, "2021/06", "Shop 2", 387779.49),
    ],
}


wow, really creative answer, thank you.

@David542 Thanks, but personally I'd make normal def window_func() function. Readability counts.

one last question (maybe I should put it in a new SO question). Instead of just getting an array of the quarters, sorted by such, how would I get the array of original rows, sorted by the quarter?)

@David542 Try to change k: [order_func(v) for v in g] to k: list(g). That way the values of final dictionary will be lists of rows sorted by order_func

I just posted an updated question, hopefully that's different enough that it's not a duplicate (or maybe it can be changed to a named function instead).
